# Google’s Calculator API not working?

Tags: php

I am using Google’s Calculator API. I have to pass dynamic values to the google url as below:

```
 $url = 'http://www.google.com/ig/calculator?hl=en&q=' . urlEncode($amount . $currency . '=?' . $exchangeIn);
```

But I am getting the following exception from the google.

```
Warning: file_get_contents(http://www.google.com/ig/calculator?hl=en&q=13,000,000pkr=?cad) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 503 Service Unavailable in /home/..../public_html/config/config.php on line 48
```

My function for this is as:

```
function exchangeRate($amount, $currency, $exchangeIn) {

$url = 'http://www.google.com/ig/calculator?hl=en&q=' . urlEncode($amount . $currency . '=?' . $exchangeIn);


$data = file_get_contents($url);

if(!$data) {
    throw new Exception('Could not connect');
}

$json = new Services_JSON(SERVICES_JSON_LOOSE_TYPE);        

$array = $json->decode($data);

if(!$array) {
    throw new Exception('Could not parse the JSON');
}

if($array['error']) {
    throw new Exception('Google reported an error: ' . $array['error']);
}

return number_format($array['rhs']);

}
 echo exchangeRate('9,200,000', 'pkr', 'cad')
```

Can somebody what is wrong with my code or something wrong with this google api ?

Thanks

Comment: Works for me: http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/k3a-jp9 Regardless, you probably don't want to use that service, iGoogle will be shut down by the end of this month.

Answer (score 0):

I also created currency calculator using Google’s Calculator API like that. Below is my code.

Usage:

simply use your own URL like: *yourdomain.com/file.php?from=USD&to=EUR&q=10*

The PHP Script:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isSet($_GET['from']) && isSet($_GET['to']) && isSet($_GET['q'])) {
  $from = preg_replace('/[^A-Z]/','',$_GET['from']);
  $to = preg_replace('/[^A-Z]/','',$_GET['to']);
  $q = preg_replace('/[^0-9\.]/','',$_GET['q']);

  echo currency($from,$to,$q);
}
function currency($from_Currency,$to_Currency,$amount) {
  $cookieName = md5("$from_Currency|$to_Currency|$amount");
  if(isSet($_COOKIE["$cookieName"])) {
    echo $_COOKIE["$cookieName"];
  }
  else {
    $amount = urlencode($amount);
    $from_Currency = urlencode($from_Currency);
    $to_Currency = urlencode($to_Currency);
    $url = "http://www.google.com/ig/calculator?hl=en&q=$amount$from_Currency=?$to_Currency";
    $ch = curl_init();
    $timeout = 0;
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch,  CURLOPT_USERAGENT , $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
    $rawdata = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $data = html_entity_decode($rawdata);
    $data = str_replace(array('lhs','rhs','error','icc',': '),array('"lhs"','"rhs"','"error"','"icc"',':'),$data);


    $row = json_decode($data,true);
    if(preg_match('/million/',$row['rhs'])) {
      $x = 1000000;
    }
    else if(preg_match('/billion/',$row['rhs'])) {
      $x = 1000000000;
    }
    else {
      $x = 1;
    }
    $result = preg_replace('/[^0-9\.]/','',$row['rhs']);
    $kurs = $result * $x;
    if($row['icc'] == 'true') {
      setcookie("$cookieName", number_format($kurs,2), time()+3600);
      return number_format($kurs,2);
    }
    else {
      return "Not available";
    }
  }
}
?>
```